# Can a .Net Core 3.1 self-contained app run on Windows 2008?

Tags: .net-core, windows-server-2008, .net-core-3.1

a thing I cant find in any documentation.
.Net Core 3.1 is not supported on Windows Server 2008 as far as I see.
Did that means that also a self-contained published version also dont work there?

Comment: Seems like an easy thing to just test does it not?

Comment: Your question asks something completely different from the title. Given that W2K8 is out of support, (it's the Vista wave after all) you'll have to just test this, knowing that any problems or bugs (TLS1.2!) won't be fixed unless your company has a support contract with Microsoft and actually pays Microsoft to develop a fix

Comment: `a thing I cant find in any documentation.` precisely because the OS [has reached End-Of-Life](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4456235/end-of-support-for-windows-server-2008-and-windows-server-2008-r2)

Comment: I highly doubt it will work. The runtime needs to run on the target OS/version, _regardless_ of how it’s been made available.

Comment: The oldest supported .NET Core version, 2.1 [supports Windows 2008R2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=netcore21). .NET Core 3.1 requires 2012 R2

Answer (score 0):

dotnet publish -c release --self-contained  -r win7-x64
Works with .netcore 6 and  3.1